# How to set a option on Chosen.js via server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

Im developing a website using ASP.NET MVC 5, with a multiple select using Chosen.js. My action is this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {       
           var states = GetStates();      
            ViewBag.States = new SelectList(states.OrderBy(o => o.Id), "Value", "Name");
            return View();            
    }
```

And in the view:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.States,
        ViewBag.States as SelectList, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"multiple", "multiple"},
            {"class", "chosen-container-multi"},
            {"placeholder", "State"},
            {"id", "State"}
        });
```

It works fine, but I would like to pré select the user state before load the page. Perhaps something like:

```
     ViewBag.States = new SelectList(states.OrderBy(o => o.Id), "Value", "Name","UserStateId");
```

but it not works. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went to this approach:

Created a new string property on the model called `UserState`, then i get the user state and assign it to that property:

```
ViewBag.States= new SelectList(states.OrderBy(o => o.Id), "Value", "Name");
var model = new ModelDTO {  UserState = states.Single(p => p.Id.Equals(stateId)).Value};
 return View(model);
```

Then on the view i simply get it:

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.States,
    ViewBag.States as SelectList, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"multiple", "multiple"},
        {"class", "chosen-container-multi"},
        {"placeholder", "State"},
        {"id", "State"}
    });

 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#StatesListBox").chosen();
        $('#StatesListBox').val("@Model.UserState");
        $('#StatesListBox').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `ListBoxFor()` generates `<select multiple="multiple">` so you don't need to add it again. But `multiple="multiple"` means you are creating a `<select>` element that allows you to select multiple items yet in the comments above you state you only want to select a single item (very unclear what you really want to do). And you cant name the `SelectList` the same as the property your binding to. Just make it `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserState, ViewBag.States as SelectList, new { @class = "..." })`

Comment: And you do not need `$('#StatesListBox').val("@Model.UserState");` - if you bind to property `UserState`, and its value matches one of the options, then it will be selected when the view is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can't name the `ViewBag` property the same as your model property. Your listbox is binding to your model property `States` so the options that are selected will be based on the value of `States`. Since your not returning a model to your view `States` is null, therefore no options are selected.

Start by using a view model that represents what you want to display/edit in the view

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int[] SelectedStates { get; set; }
  public SelectList StatesList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (note I'm assuming here that `State` contains a property `int Id` (to bind to) and a property `string Name` (the display value) and that you want to preselect the states with `Id=2` and `Id=5`)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{ 
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();      
  var states = GetStates().OrderBy(o => o.Id);
  model.StatesList = new SelectList(states, "Id", "Name");  
  model.SelectedStates = new int[] { 2, 5 }; // set the value of the options you want to preselect
  return View(model);            
}
```

View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStates, Model.StatesList, new { @class = "chosen-container-multi" })
```

Assuming you have 10 States with `Id` between 1 and 10, then the 2nd and 5th options will now be selected when the page is first rendered. When you submit your form, property `SelectedStates` will contain and array of the values selected by the user.

Side note: `ListBoxFor()` already adds the attributes `multiple="multiple"` and `id="SelectedStates"`

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion, but I went to a different approach, since a user can only have one state. Ill post it on a new answer.

Comment: Then change `int[] SelectedStates` to `int SelectedState` and use `@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, Model.StatesList)` Other wise everything else applies